# Image sequence render not working after reopening file

Tags: rendering, animation, image

After saving and closing the blender file, I opened it back up and now the image sequence render will not work. Blender only renders one image of the sequence. Hopefully I am not missing something super simple but I didn't change the settings from the first time it worked.

[image: Scene with image render settings]